# How to test whether particular text is present or not in case of selenium RC . browser is IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-rc

I'm using selenium RC from past 3 months . I'm using Internet explorer why because my application works only in IE. everything is going fine but the problem is i'm not able to verify text even though text is present in the page. i'm using following code to verify text.

```
if(s.isTextPresent("Opportunities"))
            {
                System.out.println("continue");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("error");

    }
```

above text is present in the application but still it is printing error

```
<td>
<td>
<th title="Sort by Owner" class="ms-crm-List-Sortable" entityname="opportunity" >
   <nobr>
     ...Text - Owner
     ..<img class="ms-crm-List-Sortable" alt="" src="http://dmgt-t complete="complete"/>
<td>
<th title="Sort by Topic" class="ms-crm-List-Sortable" entityname="opportunity" >
<td>
```

HTML format of my page is like above.. i need to verify the text 'Owner'
 i'm unable to verify using the statement 
 if(selenium.isTextPresent("Owner"))

if condition is giving false but text is present in the page

Comment: can u post the DOM? Chances are that the text is contained within a frame

Comment: Le gowda ru trying to check text from image?

Comment: no maga. it is normal text only... selenium is not able to verify that text.. wait i ll sent you DOM

Comment: Le use get.text(locator) and verify using if(==). locator could be either xpath,csspath or any id or name of element.

Comment: try this it may work.      xpath=//th[@title='Sort by Owner']

Comment: yes maga........ it will work for verifyElement(//th[@title='Sort by Owner']) but it is not working for verifyText(Owner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le use get.text(locator) and verify using if(==). locator could be either xpath,csspath or any id or name of element
xpath=//th[@title='Sort by Owner']

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's because the text isn't present at the point in which you check it.
If you can upgrade to Selenium v2 try using the waitForText method, it's documented [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html),
otherwise wrap your call to is text present with a method that accepts a timeout value and loop checking is text present until it is, or the timeout expires eg

```
public bool IsTextPresent(string text, int millisecondsToWait) {
    Date start = new Date();
    while ((new Date().getTime() - start.getTime()) < millisecondsToWait) {
        if (s.isTextPresent(text)) return true;
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    return false;
}
```